# lost changes with git stash, cannot revert

Tags: git

I did a bunch of modification on working branch, then `git stash`.
I don't know if this is normal but I got some wierd warnings in terminal:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 17: git-sh-setup: No such file or director
y
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 18: git-sh-i18n: No such file or directory

C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 19: require_work_tree: command not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 20: cd_to_toplevel: command not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 186: /logs/refs/stash: No such file or dir
ectory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 267: say: command not found
HEAD is now at 73b4e15 bug in resend email
```

I created a new branch, wanted to apply the stashed changes `git checkout -b new_branch; git stash apply`.
This gave me:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 17: git-sh-setup: No such file or director
y
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 18: git-sh-i18n: No such file or directory

C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 19: require_work_tree: command not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 20: cd_to_toplevel: command not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 396: eval_gettext: command not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 396: die: command not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 424: eval_gettext: command not found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Freeware\Git\1.9.5/libexec/git-core\git-stash: line 424: die: command not found
usage: git merge-recursive <base>... -- <head> <remote> ...
```

No changes were applied... And I cannot come back before stash. I surely messed up, but is there any way to revert losses on the first branch, before stash and checkout?

Comment: This may be an X/Y question, as it looks more like you've broken your `PATH` or something.

Comment: 1.9.5 is very old version. Consider installing latest Git for Windows. Also you seem to have installed to non-default path, try installing it with all defaults

Answer (score 0):

There is something very wrong with your configuration, such that the `git-stash` script cannot find other scripts it depends on to do its work.  As such it is very hard for us to know what state things were left in.

I don't really want to guess, but I will say that I'm pessimistic.  I'm surprised the script got far enough to modify your working directory or index, but from what you describe it sounds like it did; and it's not at all clear that things would've been properly written to the database.  But again, that's 99% speculation.

So job one is to find out why the script is acting up.  Do you have git properly installed?  I assume it's been working, for other operations?  If on windows, did you remember to launch a git-enabled shell instance ("git bash", "git cmd", etc.)?  Did you have to do anything unusual (like copy a binary or give a full path) to invoke git in the first place?

There are too many variables for me to walk you through every contingency, but I'd start with those kinds of questions, because the error messages (*not* warnings) that you got from `git-stash` are **not** normal.

Once you've figured that out, the next job is to assess the damage and see if it's recoverable.  You can use `git status` to confirm if anything is still in your index.  You can use `git reflog stash` to see if somehow a new stash commit was created in all that mess.